# Intern.js: Load Firefox/Safari extension via config

Tags: selenium, firefox, safari, intern

I am using Intern.js for functional tests on browser extensions.  I have been able to get a chrome extension pre-loaded into the browser with this config:

```
{
  "capabilities": {
    "selenium-version": "3.5.2"
  },
  "tunnel": "null",
  "tunnelOptions": {
    "host": "selenium.hostaddres.com:4444",
    "port": "4444",
    "path": "/wd/hub"
  },
  "environments": [
    { "browserName": "chrome",
      "chromeOptions": {
        "extensions": ["Q3IyNAMAAABFAgAAEqwECqYCMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BA+LXpUNZoDajG6ywIDAQABEoACNd+U4xNvCvtf7m........."
      },
      "browserTimeout": 10000 }
  ],
  "reporters": ["pretty"],
  "functionalSuites": ["dist/functional/tests/**/*.js"]
}
```

The `extensions` property is a base 64 encoded crx (chrome extension) file.

I have not been able to find any documentation that would provide similar configuration for Firefox or Safari.  I understand that there are Selenium specific ways of doing this, but I would ideally like to stay within the Intern way of setting this up. Any help with example working configs would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Intern doesn't actually deal with browser-specific configuration itself, it just passes the options you give it directly to Selenium when creating a session. The tricky thing is figuring out what options are available for any given browser.

For Firefox, you'll probably want to create a profile that contains the extension(s) you're interested in, and then tell Firefox to use that profile during tests.

You used to have to zip up and base64 encode the custom profile (the basic process is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180890/dojo-intern-set-firefox-profile-name)), but now you can probably get away with just pointing to its location on your system if testing locally. The relevant geckodriver options are described [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/blob/master/README.md#mozfirefoxoptions). Assuming you were using a zipped and base64-encoded profile, your config might look like:

```
"environments": {
  "browserName": "firefox",
  "moz:firefoxOptions": {
    "profile": "UEsDBBQACAAIACynEk..."
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jason0x43 - I'm going to try out your solution this week.